trino jars/classes not accessible during maven compilation. Getting "cannot access" issue for any classes from the trino jars
I have added trino jars (trino-main,trino-spi & trino-parser) in my maven project. When I open the project in IDE, I can see the jars getting properly loaded and I am able to see the suggestions for trino classes as well.
But when I try to compile the same project I am getting "cannot access" errors for these classes:
For example in IDE I am able to write below import with taking editor suggestions for classes in package (io.trino.spi.type):
import io.trino.spi.type.TypeSignature;

But for the class during compilation phase, I am getting below error:

[ERROR] MY_PROJECT_FILE_PATH/ByteType.java:5:24:  error: cannot access TypeSignature

I have checked the jars are showing that class properly:
$ jar tf trino-spi-385.jar | grep TypeSignature
io/trino/spi/type/TypeSignatureParameter$1.class
io/trino/spi/type/TypeSignatureParameter.class
io/trino/spi/type/NamedTypeSignature.class
io/trino/spi/type/TypeSignature.class

This i have tried with multiple versions (392, 440, 451, 468) but for all I am getting the same issue.
How to fix this?
